# How the Botton Bar and Navigation Drawer can work with JAVA?

Tags: java, android

When I click run, I get the following error:

```
MainActivity@7cd9101 does not have a NavController set on 21312
```

I solve the problem with the same layout using Kotlin. But i don't know how to "translate" the code for JAVA.

Here is the main layout:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/slide_nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</RelativeLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/slide_nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:menu="@menu/slide_drawer" />
```

And here is the code on Kotlin that i want to translate to JAVA:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)


    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.slide_nav_view)
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow
        ), drawerLayout
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me :c I tried a lot of time and I don't know how to solve this.

If you could put in the answer the java class code I will appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
```

Which should be

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
```